# Qual melhor forma de me conectar a um servidor Web, utilizando Java Web?

Tags: java, ajax, servidor, socket

Estou trabalhando com uma aplicação Java Web, a qual vai constantemente pegar um arquivo txt, e atualizar esses dados constantemente em uma página HTML, mas não sei qual a melhor opção para me conectar a um servidor web, eu deveria usar sockets ou uma conexão por post com Ajax seria melhor ? Eu preciso pegar um documento txt no servidor, constantemente, e sempre atualizar esses dados em uma página HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi é um servidor web, um local alocado, sem aplicação rodando que apenas mantem esse arquivo .txt la dentro.

Se no seu servidor é possível implementar alguma aplicação você poderia fazer uma requisição HTTP GET, assim sempre que acessada retornaria o arquivo desejado para sua outra estrutura Java que o necessita, podendo até já formatar-lo e acertar sua apresentação.

- GET: Requisita um representação do recurso especificado (O mesmo recurso pode ter várias representações, ao exemplo de serviços que retornam XML e JSON).

Agora se não for possível criar essa aplicação no servidor e o arquivo esta disponível para acesso, você poderia busca-lo pelo caminho físico.

Acredito que [URLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) é a maneira mais básica de fazer isto, para situações simples resolve, mas para casos mais complexos, como authentication, post e multipart não serve, por isso o melhor é usar o [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/) (Apache HttpComponents).